# Insert multiple records into table for each user in another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to create notification application in node js and I just created a database with these three tables in SQL Server:

**tbluser**

```
user_id
user_name
```

**tbluser_notification**

```
user_id
noti_id
read
```

**tblnotification**

```
noti_id
noti_title
noti_mesg
noti_create
noti_sender_id
```

My question is: whenever I insert a notification into `tblnotification`, I want to insert a record for each user into the `tbluser_notification`.

Comment: Heard of CROSS JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Create after insert trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtblnotificationInsert]
    ON [dbo].[tblnotification]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO tbluser_notification (user_id, noti_id, notificationread)
    SELECT tbluser.user_id, inserted.noti_id, 0
    FROM tbluser
       CROSS JOIN inserted
END
```

Please note: I have changed the column name 'read' to 'notificationread' as read is reserved word.